# fraction multiplication - having trouble with picture

Tags: fractions

I have this problem where 3/4 x 2/3 and answer is 1/2 however, I am having hard time finding the correspondent picture from the attach file. Is the answer H or O? if yes why? I am helping my son and it's been a long while I done this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for a picture which is divided into 4 equal parts in one dimension, and 3 equal parts in the other dimension.  In the first dimension, 
if 3 out of the 4 equal subdivisions are shaded, then 3/4 of the rectangle is shaded. In the other dimension, if 2 out of the 3 equal subdivisions are shaded, then 2/3 of the rectangle is shaded.  That part of the rectangle that is shaded in both ways is the product of the fractions.  Picture E does the job.

Comment: Thanks CSR. I need to read your answer line by line and analyze. I appreciate it.

Comment: Antarc -- you might also note that the rectangle is divided into 3 times 4 = 12 equal parts, 6 of which are double colored -- and 6 out of 12 is 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not O. You need the result to be half of the total area. H will do